# What could cause a ".json is unexpected at this time" error when running a postman collection from command line using newman

Tags: command-line, postman, newman

I am attempting to use newman to run postman collection from the command line. I have been successful before, but with this most recent collection I am getting an error. I am using the following command

```
newman run [urlforjcollection] --reporters cli,json,html --reporter-json-
export C:\outputfile.json --reporter-
html-export C:\outputfile.html -e 
c:\QAEnvironment.json
```

This fails to run and I get the error .json was unexpected at this time. As I said I used this exact command on another collection and it worked fine.

Does anyone know what could case this issue? Is it something wrong with my command or is there some setting in postman that can cause it?

Comment: could you show the command which worked?

Comment: The command that worked is the exact same command, I just pointed to a different collection.

Comment: I understand.. could you show the entire command anyway, please?

Comment: newman run [collection url] --reporters cli,json,html --reporter-json-export C:\outputfile.json --reporter-html-export C:\outputfile.html -e \Postman_Environment\BioPeoplev2.postman_environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Googled your error and it seems to be a problem with the command line rather than Postman; specifically, the need to use double quotes while specifying file locations. Try this:

```
newman run [urlforjcollection] --reporters cli,json,html --reporter-json-
export "C:\outputfile.json" --reporter-
html-export "C:\outputfile.html" -e 
"c:\QAEnvironment.json"
```

Comment: Wow, for some reason I didn't have this on the other one and it worked, now I wonder what is wrong with it, but either way this worked.

Comment: Not using double quotes also works in some cases, but using them is the safest option in all cases. Cheers :)